# How to fetch the name of the url inside the laravel mailer?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a webpage with 4 different urls

```
www.sample.com\home
www.sample.com\about
www.sample.com\products
www.sample.com\contact
```

I have a `contact form` in all the pages of my webpage.

I need to know the `Page`, from where the contact form is submitted from either(home, about, products or services).

I use **laravel mailer** to send mail, once the contact form is submitted.

**Contact form**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{substr(strrchr(url()->current(),'/'),1)}}">

<form method="POST" action="sendEmail">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
     
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  value ="{{ old('email') }}"/>
                                    
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="body" id="message" rows="5"> {{ old('message') }}</textarea>
    <button class ="primary"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as PostRequest;

 public  function store()
    {
       $data = request()->validate([
         'name' => 'required',
          'email'   => 'required|email',
         'body' =>  'required'
      ]);
      // To get the current URL
      $currentPage = PostRequest::input('url');
     
       \Mail::send('E-mail view', $data, $currentPage, function($message) use ($data, $currentPage){
               $message->to('abc@xyz.com')
                       ->from($data['email'], $data['name'])
                       ->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name'])
                       ->returnPath($currentPage)
                       ->subject('Notification');
         });
        return back();
    }
```

I need the `URL` as `home`, `about`, `products`, `contact`, from where the Contact form is submitted from not the form action `sendEmail` inside the `E-mail View blade file`

**Email View Blade**:

```
<p> $name </p>
<p> $email</p>
<p> $currentPage </p>
```

It throws an Error

```
Function name must be a string
```

How to pass the **current URL** from Where the Form is submiited from (home, about,..) to `Mail`?

Could anyone please help?
Many thanks.

Comment: Laravel has `URL::current()`. You can create hidden field in your form and pass `URL::current()` as value and receive it in the target url.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as PostRequest;

 public  function store()
    {
       $data = request()->validate([
         'name' => 'required',
          'email'   => 'required|email',
         'body' =>  'required'
      ]);
      // To get the current URL
      $currentPage = request()->url();
      $data['currentPage'] = $currentPage;
     
       \Mail::send('E-mail view', $data, function($message) use ($data, $currentPage){
               $message->to('abc@xyz.com')
                       ->from($data['email'], $data['name'])
                       ->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name'])
                       ->returnPath($currentPage)
                       ->subject('Notification');
         });
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: By adding ` $data['currentPage'] = $currentPage;`. I couldn't see any errors. But, in E-mail View blade file `<p> {{ $currentPage }} </p>` shows nothing. I need the URL(home, about, products,...) from where the contact form is submitted from. Could you please help?

Comment: Try changing: $currentPage = request()->url() WITH $currentPage = PostRequest::input('url');
But it is not safe, because user can change your hidden input's value and send whatever he wants.

Comment: Because, dd($currentPage) shows `NULL`. How to get the value of the hidden `input` field from View to controller?

Comment: You should write "<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{substr(strrchr(url()->current(),'/'),1)}}">" This line inside <form></form> tags, not outside of it

Comment: If I write it inside the form, It gives the `URL` as `sendEmail` Which the form is redirected to. I need the URL as `Home`, `about`, etc.. from Where the form the submitted from. Also,  $currentPage = request()->url()  gives the url as `www.sample.com\sendEmail`.